# recovery expectations/timeline for ankle-joint osteosynthesis removal

Tags: procedural-expectations, recovery, ankle

A 70 year relative complains on occasional pain due to osteosynthesis titanium remaining in a leg, also she fears potential complication if her diabetes starts to progress. Does it make sense to remove considering it is there for 10 years? Can one expect her walking and travelling in a month or few?